# Wait until string.contains() condition is met

Tags: c#, loops

I'm reading a file to my C# application and decompressing a tile_data BLOB using a gzip stream. I'm currently accessing the BLOB data through this method:

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, DbConn);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
bool isMet = false;
while (reader.Read())
{
    using (var file = reader.GetStream(0))
    using (var unzip = new GZipStream(file, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(unzip))
    {
        var line = fileReader.ReadLine();
        while (!fileReader.EndOfStream)
        {

        }
        Console.WriteLine("End of tile_data");
     }
}
reader.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Reader closed");
Console.ReadKey();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I'm looking to wait until the `fileReader` detects `"tertiary"` (string) and then prints all data afterwards. I attempted to use a `bool` and a nested `while loop` but it came back as an infinite loop, hence the question.

The code that I used (and failed with):

```
if (line.Contains("tertiary"))
 {
    isMet = true;
 }
 while (!fileReader.EndOfStream && isMet)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(line);
 }
```

How can I perform an operation only with my `fileReader`  once a condition has been met?

Comment: Check answer. Tell me it is working or not for you.

Comment: In your while loop, you're not reading/progressing the fileReader, hence you will never reach the end of the stream and your while will be infinite. You should enclose a 'line = fileReader.ReadLine()' in your while to progress and keep reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fileReader.EndOfStream` loop will only work if your stream has only a single line. The problem is that you're only reading from the stream once - so unless you've already read the whole thing, you're in an endless loop.

Instead, do something like this:

```
string line;

while ((line = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  if (line.Contains("...")) break; // Or whatever else you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. It find any character in the string. It is working for me.

```
string matchStr = "tertiary";
                if (line.Any(matchStr.Contains)
                            {
                                isMet = true;
                            }
                            while (!fileReader.EndOfStream && isMet)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(line);
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `var line = fileReader.ReadLine();` be inside the while loop?

```
while (!fileReader.EndOfStream)
{
     var line = fileReader.ReadLine();
     // do some other stuff
}
```

Comment: Oops, it was before but I guess I forgot to move it back before posting here, was testing a few things. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var yourval;
var secval = fileReader.ReadLine()

while ((yourval = secval ) != null)
{
   if (line.Contains("your string here")) 
   {
      break;
   }
}
```